# What was the first interactive OS to run each command in a new process?

Tags: history, operating-system

I was prompted to ask this by another recent question about early Unix process structure.

The more-or-less contemporaneous systems I'm aware of (built 1960s to 1970s) mostly gave you a software structure, often called a 'job', when you signed on through a terminal.  For commands not built in to the command interpreter, core would be allocated to the job, and the command program executed within the job.

I don't think Multics counts; my understanding is that the multiprocess approach was designed but not used.

TENEX used a multiprocess structure but I'm not sure it qualifies as first.

Comment: Early computer monitors/command interpreters had a "run" command that was used to explicitly load and run an program (after completion, control would return to the command interpreter).  I'm not sure what system first had the idea of "implicit run" -- entering a command that the command interpreter did not understand would just make it the argument of a "run" command and try to run it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea of having a hierarchy of child processes(*1) and using a Fork-like mechanism is quite tied to Unix as an operating system, but not originated there. To my knowledge it was [Melvin Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melvin_Conway) who first wrote in 1962 about a possible software structure based on a concept of "forking" and "joining" of processes to achieve parallel execution on multiprocessor systems. While forking one does not need any bookkeeping of process relation, the later process of joining (synchronizing) the execution does greatly benefit thereof.

Linus Nyman and Mikael Laakso mention in their 2016 paper ***[Notes on the history of fork-and-join](https://helda.helsinki.fi/dhanken/bitstream/handle/123456789/167488/Nyman_Laakso_2016.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)*** that Conway did remark that *"the fork-join notion has
been around for a while"* before he wrote his paper. The first real implementation of this father-son relation was eventually done with [Project Genie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Genie) in 1964 by [Laurence Peter Deutsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Peter_Deutsch) (*2) on a 24 bit [SDS 940](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDS_940) machine. Project Genie inspired many others not at least [TOPS-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOPS-20). And the rest is history.

Or not. As to come to Unix' process structure it might be important to understand Multics view of process and memory. A process was for the most part a list of segments mapped into its address space. So far it may sound like any other OS, but Multics also tried to remove the idea of different storage levels by not acknowledging RAM as something in its own right, but always being a representation of a disk file. So not just Code, but each and every memory segment (during lifetime of a process) had to have an associated file. One where it could be saved to and loaded from.

Beside providing a stringent structure, it had several advantages. Libraries or utilities could be just called by dynamically creating a new segment assigned with the file name of the library in question and right away calling a function. The OS would then map the code, and execution continued. Having this, it was no big deal to invoke a new process the same way, by setting up a list of segments with associated file names (at least one with the code) and then initiating a new process with this segment list - while staying in memory and waiting for a return - or not.

Sounds complex and it is. Ken Thompson once called it "*overdesigned and overbuilt and over everything*" (*3) and I think he's right. Multics was conceived top-down with a huge theoretical overhead. Then again, he did like the idea of having an exchangeable shell (contrary to an OS built-in EXEC) and executing programs as separate processes while the shell (and thus all prior programs) stay in memory and wait. So long story short, the easy creation of new processes was kept while the tight coupling of memory and disk was thrown overboard for Unix.

---

*1 - There are many other ways to handle processes other than the Unix way, usually more loosely bound and/or using threading or interrupt level like scheduling, avoiding the hierarchical problems of fork-join.

*2 - Most well known due to his free Postscript implementation [Ghostscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript)

*3 - P.463 on Peter Seibel's book *[Coders at Work](http://www.one-shore.com/aaron/books/coders-at-work.pdf)*

Comment: Fair enough, but process-per-command  doesn't require the semantics of fork.  The possibly more common paradigm of creating a new process with a new image (in one operation) will suffice.  Nevertheless, the pointer to SDS940 is a good one. I'll need to go and refresh my memory of how it handled this.

Comment: @dave Well, yes and no. Joining needs a clear coupling of the parent process and it's child. To show the line of development here, I added a few lines about multics and it's influence on Unix regarding process creation.

Comment: By 'fork' I understand that the child process be created with a copy of the parent address space. Parent-child relationship, and in particular awaiting child termination, can and did exist without that. Whether you care to call that 'join' seems like a matter of taste.

Comment: @dave Not realy, that is the meaning fork became _after_ it was used by Unix - and Unix being the first OS that did so with a copy of the parent address space. As shown, the term 'fork' was used way before Unix and itself is not related to the copy part. Also, **if this (child baing a copy of parent) is one of the requirements of your question, then Unix is the answer**. If not, then Multics is a good candidate for an answer to the question in your title - and Genie maybe as well, except I do not know enough details to be complete sure. Maybe you want to better clarify what exactly you ask for

Comment: OK, I'll agree to your opinion on the term 'fork'. Address-space copy is not part of the question. The question is really about getting a new 'container' for each command rather than putting the command in an existing 'container'.  Counter-example: the TOPS-10 monitor ran programs in the user's single job.

Comment: I think the SDS940 system might be my answer. I don't think Multics is it, because Multics loaded command segments into an existing process. (Organick's book implies otherwise but AFAIK that did not transpire) and called them within that process context.  https://www.multicians.org/myths.html#eio1

Comment: @dave True. But Id be careful here. After all, we compare different philosopies. THe same way the term Task is used in like a dozend differend ways in the /370 world, process may have different meanings. For example as long as the father process is stoped during child execution (which is default on the command line), there is no differentce between Multics' way and Unix' way. A new segment is created and run.  Unix combines several steps into one to simplify, which in turn restricts usage.

Comment: If shared libraries, gets added to the picture, Unix no is no longer the simple way, as it needs a seperate shared memory/library API, something basic Multics functionality of segments already offers. Seams like the usual game of trade-off. By making memory/segment handling independant of process creation (and the later more often than not unneccessary) Multics had a fine scale toolset to handle various situation. Unix in contrast 'simplified' the situation by a single but complex tool, which saved effort o start with, but had to add additional APIs on the long run to make up for it.

Comment: @dave For one, the SDS940 was a computer, not an operating system. Next, Genie/Tymshare did heavy relay on a function group called "_fork and gate_", which was explicite made to *not* load a new program, but reuse existing coe - after all, memory was a premium. Tymshares process view was an open one with processes interacting on many levels, icluding direct memory read and write - quite contrary to the closed concepts of Unix. In General, I do not belive it is usefull to trim an answer to fit a specific expectations, as it should be about the topic, shouldn't it?

Comment: Excuse my brevity: for "SDS940 system" read "The SDS940 Timesharing System".

Comment: Returning to this after all this time (!) - yes, I'm convinced that the Project Genie implementation (which of course became the SDS940 Timesharing System) was the first.  Though I can't find a manual that actually **says** the Executive ran each command in a fork, it seems inevitable given the process structure.

Comment: @another-dave, I'm in contact with someone who is trying to get a BTSS and/or TYMCOM-IX (Tymeshare's updated BTSS) system assembled and running.  He says there is a separate EXEC.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff,  Not sure I follow you.  As far as I understand it, the exec is indeed a separate program (unlike, say, the tops10 command decoder) but did you mean that the exec runs each command in a separate fork, which I think was the unclear point?  But I guess we'll find out when it's running!  Thanks for the update.